# Probability - Conditional (1-1)

Tags: probability

Consider the events A and B from a sample space **Ω**. 
 [https://postimg.org/image/4vl99gjs9/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rewrP.jpg)

Select one:

a. $P(A\cup B)= P(A)+P(B)$

b. $P(\overline{A\cap B})= P(B) − P(A\cap B)$

c. $P(\bar A\cap\bar B)= 1 − P(A\cap B)$

d. None of the above

N.B: The Correct answer is **b**, The " ¯ " sign above letters A and B. Which means that the event is not happening. Please explain why is the answer **b**

Comment: draw Venn diagram, this will become immediately clear

Comment: When i draw. are A and B joint or disjoint?

Comment: It doesn't matter

Comment: N.B. Seems wrong. Suitably ignored in Answer. Also, unless you are told A and B are disjoint, it is best to draw the Venn diagram with A and B overlapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rearranging the given equation gives: $$\mathsf P(B)=\mathsf P(A\cap B)+\mathsf P(\bar A\cap B)$$

Is that familiar?

> Now, by definition of complement, $A$ and $\bar A$ are disjoint, so then too are $A\cap B$ and $\bar A\cap B$.    Probability is additive for the union of disjoint events.   Applying distribution to the union of the events 'factors out' $B$, and $A\cup\bar A$ is the entire sample space.   The intersection of $B$ and $\Omega$ is just $B$, leaving us with $\mathsf P(B)=\mathsf P(B)$ which is incontrovercial.
>
>  Therefore **b** is a true statement.

---

> Also, its called the Law of Total Probability

---

Can you explain why the other answers are *not* generally correct?